# Getting location name from latitude, longitude

Tags: android, location, geocoding

I've started programming in Android recently. In my app I want to tell the user their location **in words**, for example: "Washington" or "New York". I've seen I can get latitude and longitude but I want to tell the location in words (probebly a string).

Can I do it? And if I can, how?

How much is it accurate? Can it give me the name of the city or only the state?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example code using a Thread and a Handler to get the Geocoder answer without blocking the UI.

Geocoder call procedure, can be located in a Helper class

```
public static String getAddressFromLocation(final Location location, final Context context, final Handler handler) 
     {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override public void run() 
         {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());   
            String result = null;
            try {
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) 
                    {
                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    // sending back first address line and locality
                    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality()+","+address.getCountryName();
                        }
                } 
             catch (IOException e)
                {
                Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
                } 
         }
    };
    thread.start();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using reverse [geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html). A sample code for that:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latValue,
                    longValue, 1);

            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder(
                        "Address:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                                    "\n");
                }
                myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
        }
```

Just place this code after you are getting latitude and longitude values.

Answer (score -3):

Just check out this you will get every thing you want,

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html

Comment: An example of the problem of link-only answers.  This link appears to be dead.